# Normalize sum(case when ..)

Tags: r, prediction, netezza, training-data, normalize

In Netezza I ran the following query to make the nominal variables into binomial ones and sum them up:

```
sum(case when c.COUNTRYCODE = 'US' then 1 else 0 end) as US
```

I do this for multiple countries and other similar (categorical) variables.

Then, I use R to normalize the data with:

```
normalize <- function(x) { return( (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)) ) }
```

I put them in a data frame in R:

```
all_n <- as.data.frame(lapply(all[,c(1:56)], normalize))
```

and make a train and test data. 
Next I run this line of code:

```
m1<-knn(train=alltrain,test=alltest,cl=alltrain_target,k=53)
```

All seems to work and the prediction for k-nearest neighbor seems to do good too as it predicts it right. I check this with

```
table(alltest_target,m1)
```

in R.

However, is this method okay as I normalize sum(cases..)? Or should I go about it in a different way? So is normalizing sum(cases..) correct?

Comment: I think your question is more suitable for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Oh okay, thanks danas ;). I'll ask there then